# Sitecore 10.1 Installation error with Sitecore Installation Assistance (SIA)

Tags: installation, sitecore

Sitecore Installation Assistance (SIA) fails when installing pre-requisites with the following error:

```
[-------- DownloadWebPlatformInstaller : DownloadFile ------------------------]
[DownloadWebPlatformInstaller]:[Download] https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi => C:\Users\AriaA\AppData\Local\Temp\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
    Error downloading https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
    [TIME] 00:00:48
    Error downloading https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be resolved by updating the `[install files folder]\Prerequisites.json` file and re-try the installation.

Just change the `DefaultValue` key of the JSON as per below.

```json
"WebPlatformDownload": {
   "Type": "String",
   "Description": "Download location of Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0",
   "DefaultValue": "https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/9/849DBCF2-DFD9-49F5-9A19-9AEE5B29341A/WebPlatformInstaller_x64_en-US.msi"
},
```

If it fails again in the future, just refer back to the download page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads

Answer (score 1):

SIA tries to download WebPlatformInstaller from a URL that no longer exists.
Download WebPlatformInstaller from the following URL and try to install pre-requisites again using SIA.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Somehow that Prerequsites.json is being recreating when script is run, so better you go and install it this from here [enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads) and then run the setup script again.